# MSTest, Accessors, Inheritance, and Private Members

Tags: unit-testing, mstest

I'm trying to write some tests for an MVC application we're developing. We have a BaseController class that contains the following:

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected string UserRole { get; private set; }
```

We then have a controller that inherits from the BaseController:

```
public class CustomFieldController : BaseController
```

I've generated private accessors for both classes (just regenerated them a few minutes ago). In one of my unit tests for CustomFieldController I want to set the UserRole, so I've got the following code:

```
CustomFieldController controller = new CustomFieldController();
CustomFieldController_Accessor accessor = new CustomFieldController_Accessor( 
    new PrivateObject( controller, new PrivateType( typeof( BaseController ) ) ) );

accessor.UserRole = "OTHER";
```

Every time I try to run this test it throws an exception on the last line stating:

> The member specified (CustomFieldEdit) could not be found. You might need to regenerate your private accessor, or the member may be private and defined on a base class. If the latter is true, you need to pass the type that defines the member into PrivateObject's constructor.

As far as I can tell, I've done what it says. Not only have I recently regenerated the private accessor, but I am passing the type that defines the member into PrivateObject's constructor.

Any thoughts as to what I'm missing here? I know I can make it work by taking the "private" off the property setter, but I'd rather not do that if I can avoid it (don't want subclass implementers thinking they can inject a value into that property).

Comment: Just don't use these private accessor stuff - it only makes you write rubbish code. You should only unit-test the public interface of your class.

Comment: Perhaps my post was unclear. I'm not trying to test the property (that would be pretty stupid). In order to test all the code paths of a couple of the methods that property needs to have a value in it.

I also disagree that only the public interface should be tested. Private methods often form the foundation of the public interface, and being able to test those smaller units of work to ensure they all do their thing correctly seems to me to be right in line with what unit testing is all about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`CustomFieldController controller = new CustomFieldController();

    var po = new PrivateObject( controller, new PrivateType( typeof( BaseController ) ) );

    CustomFieldController_Accessor accessor = new CustomFieldController_Accessor( po );`

```
po.SetFieldOrProperty("UserRole","OTHER");
```

Comment: Though this does fix the problem and I understand why it fixed it (the PrivateType needs to be added so the Accessor knows which object to look for members in upon execution), may I suggest adding a brief explanation as to why in answers for future users?